# Multi level menu from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a menu from an array in PHP.

I would like to make it more readable, so I used an array.

My array is the following:

```
$menu = array(
   'calendar' => array(
      'text'   => 'Calendar',
      'rights' => 'user'
   ),
   'customers' => array(
      'text'   => 'Customers',
      'rights' => 'user',
      'sub' => array(
         'create-new' => array(
            'text'   => 'Create new customer',
            'rights' => 'user'
         ),
         'show-customers' => array(
            'text'   => 'Show all customers',
            'rights' => 'user'
         )
      )
   )
);
```

And the PHP to parse the array:

```
buildMenu($menu);

function buildMenu($menu_array, $is_sub=FALSE) {

   $attr = (!$is_sub) ? ' id="menu"' : ' class="submenu"';
   $menu = "<ul".$attr.">";

   foreach($menu_array as $id => $properties) {
      foreach($properties as $key => $val) {
         if(is_array($val)) {
            $sub = buildMenu($val, TRUE);
         }
         else {
            $sub = NULL;
            $$key = $val;
         }
      }
      if(!isset($url)) {
         $url = $id;
      }
      $menu .= "<li><a href=".$url.">".$text."</a>".$sub."</li>";
      unset($url, $text, $sub);
   }

   return $menu . "</ul>";
}
```

Do I miss something ?

It don't echo me anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use _echo $output = buildMenu($menu);_ instead _buildMenu($menu);_

Comment: Wow, my menu is here. :) Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return will not give output you need to either use below code, inside function.

```
 echo $menu . "</ul>";
```

instead of

```
return $menu . "</ul>";
```

or use below code if you return your html output.

```
echo $output = buildMenu($menu);
```

instead of

```
buildMenu($menu);
```